# grep to find string + variation in value

Tags: linux, build, grep

I'm trying to look for a string in a log file that might change, depending on how successful the build goes.

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I am looking for when `"Failures"` & `"errors"` value is greater than 0. I was hoping I could use `grep` to determine this.

Answer (score 2):

Then just search for Failures or Errors followed by non-zero:

```
grep 'Failures: [^0]\|Errors: [^0]'
```

To search for failures **and** errors both happening, use

```
grep 'Failures: [^0,]*, Errors: [^0]'
```

Comment: This is checking if either of them matches, whereas the question says "and". Or am I missing something? If it is `&`, this is a way to do it: `awk '/Failures: [^0]/ && /Errors: [^0]/' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui: True, fixed.